# How to manage polygon data synchronization from backbone with agm-core?

Tags: angular, google-maps

The goal of my component is to get points (lat, lng) coming from the database to draw a polygon on a Google map. The Google map is correctly implemented and displays with drawing manager ok.

My problem is much more a problem of declaration.

I have the following code for the map:

```js
onMapReady(map) {
  this.initDrawingManager(map);
  this.polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: this.pointsArray,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true,
  });
}
```

On `ngOnInit()`, I am getting all the points in the following format:

[image]

I'm getting it using this function set at the bottom of the component code:

```js
getSitePoints() {
  this.siteAPI.getPoints(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.sitePoints = response;
      const pointsArray = [];
      this.sitePoints.map((item) => {
        pointsArray.push(item.Location);
        console.log(pointsArray);
        console.log('item:' + item.Location);
      });
    });
}
```

As the polygon drawing is done on the `onMapReady` event and as my Array is populated after a subscribe, in a function, polygon is not showing. Like if it was empty when received by the drawing Manager. No clue how to check this.

Also, declarations are:

```js
pointsArray = [];
sitePoints: any;
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Best Regards

Comment: It sounds like a race condition. Can you convert the function getSitePoints() to async. Then you can use the "await" keyword to init the map.

Comment: I modified : async ngOnInit() {
    this.getSiteDetails();
    await this.getSitePoints(); } // same result

Comment: remove "const pointsArray" in getSitePoints(). Use the this.pointsArray you have as a class property.

Comment: How is `onMapReady` set or called?

Comment: 1st/ Removing const, ok, this is much more clean but does not fix. 2/ the map is created with agm-core package and onMapReady() is an event. The map is showing fine. and the drawingManager too.

Comment: Can you display the rest of your component. I want to see more of the logic within your OnInit and constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded fixing my problem. Thanks to everyone for your support.

Considering that the whole angular component lifeCycle is re-run on browser refresh, manipulating thing in different lifecycle parts was not the solution.
Playing with lifeCycles is not a way to manage asynchronous data.

The solution was to get the points coming from DB on a subscribe() and then draw the polygon to ensure data is received before.

Like below :

```
this.pointsArray = [];
    this.siteAPI.getPoints(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
        .subscribe(
          response => {
          this.sitePoints = response;
          this.pointsArray = [];
          this.sitePoints.map((item) => {
            this.pointsArray.push(item.Location);
          });
        }
        ,
        err => {},
        () => {
        this.polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: this.pointsArray,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          editable: true,
          draggable: true,
          });
        // Set polygon to map
        this.polygon.setMap(map);
        }
        );}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could post complete code for this solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're not saving the data in the class property.

```
getSitePoints() {
  this.siteAPI.getPoints(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.sitePoints = response;
      //const pointsArray = []; <--- Remove
      this.sitePoints.map((item) => {
        //pointsArray.push(item.Location); <-- issue
        this.pointsArray.push(item.Location);
        console.log(this.pointsArray);
        console.log('item:' + item.Location);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ? I am thinking populating an array and give it to eat to the new google.maps.Polygon() as a parameter:this.polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: this.pointsArray, ... if I use this array as parameter, it works fine: triangleCoords = [
    { lat: 43.252967, lng: 5.379856 },
    { lat: 43.249466, lng: 5.392988 },
    { lat: 43.245153, lng: 5.395048 },
    { lat: 43.239838, lng: 5.383804 }
  ];

Comment: You are initializing google.maps.Ploygon with paths: this.pointsArray. 
The way you originally wrote the function "getSitePoints", you are not pushing to this.pointsArray. You are pushing to an array created withing the scope of the subscribe delegate function. This is why you have an empty this.pointsArray. It is empty because it was never used.

Comment: @jiver27 I am not sure to understand. How could I change this please?

Comment: Hello @jiver27  I am doing this: this.siteAPI.getPoints(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
        .subscribe((response) => {
          this.sitePoints = response;
          // this.pointsArray = [];
          this.sitePoints.map((item) => {
           **this.pointsArray.push(item.Location);**
            console.log(this.pointsArray);  this.pointsArray is showing fine in the console but looks like empty outside of the function ...

Comment: After started the debugger, I have seen that the event mapReady is fired before my Array is filled. So my problem is much more a problem of synchronization. I have so on changed the title of the question.